# Some admin modules redirect to frontend

Tags: magento, url, redirect, admin, frontend

I have created one more store in Magento. Before creation of this store, all modules worked fine. But after created this store, some of the modules will redirect to frontend.

I have googled regarding this concept and got this thread https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4623/custom-admin-url-now-some-admin-modules-redirect-to-frontend

I have followed this thread's answer. But it doesn't work for me. Most of the threads have the same answer like this thread.

Please save me guys.

Thank you

**EDIT**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <config>
  <modules>
    <Chilly_Imageslide>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Chilly_Imageslide>
</modules>
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <imageslide>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>Chilly_Imageslide</module>
                <frontName>imageslide</frontName>
            </args>
        </imageslide>
    </routers>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <imageslide>
                <file>imageslide.xml</file>
            </imageslide>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</frontend>
<admin>
    <routers>
     <adminhtml>
        <use>admin</use>
        <args>
            <modules>
                <imageslide before="Mage_Adminhtml">Chilly_Imageslide_Adminhtml</imageslide>
            </modules>
        </args>
    </adminhtml>
        <!--<imageslide>
            <use>admin</use>
            <args>
                <module>Chilly_Imageslide</module>
                <frontName>imageslide</frontName>
            </args>
        </imageslide>-->
    </routers>
</admin>
<adminhtml>
   <menu>
        <imageslide module="imageslide">
            <title>Imageslide</title>
            <sort_order>71</sort_order>               
            <children>
                <items module="imageslide">
                    <title>Manage Items</title>
                    <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                    <action>imageslide/adminhtml_imageslide</action>
                </items>
            </children>
        </imageslide>
    </menu>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <all>
                <title>Allow Everything</title>
            </all>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <imageslide>
                        <title>ImageSlide Module</title>
                        <sort_order>200</sort_order>
                    </imageslide>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>   
    </acl>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <imageslide>
                <file>imageslide.xml</file>
            </imageslide>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</adminhtml>   
<global>
    <models>
        <imageslide>
            <class>Chilly_Imageslide_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>imageslide_mysql4</resourceModel>
        </imageslide>
        <imageslide_mysql4>
            <class>Chilly_Imageslide_Model_Mysql4</class>
            <entities>
                <imageslide>
                    <table>imageslide</table>
                </imageslide>
            </entities>
        </imageslide_mysql4>
    </models>
    <resources>
        <imageslide_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>Chilly_Imageslide</module>
            </setup>
            <connection>
                <use>core_setup</use>
            </connection>
        </imageslide_setup>
        <imageslide_write>
            <connection>
                <use>core_write</use>
            </connection>


        </imageslide_write>
        <imageslide_read>
            <connection>
                <use>core_read</use>
            </connection>
        </imageslide_read>
    </resources>
    <blocks>
        <imageslide>
            <class>Chilly_Imageslide_Block</class>
        </imageslide>
    </blocks>
    <helpers>
        <imageslide>
            <class>Chilly_Imageslide_Helper</class>
        </imageslide>
    </helpers>
</global>
</config>
```

Comment: Can you post some of your code? Especiallly your config.xml.

Comment: I have added my config.xml file coding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a solution. We have set a condition like to redirect stores based on country wise! Main store for UK folks. But we are in India! So for admin access we have write condition like

```
 RewriteCond %{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE} IN$    
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !admin [NC]
 RewriteRule ^ http://www.domain.in [R=301,L]
```

It means, when try to access main store in India and that url must not have the keyword "admin", it will redirect to given domain.For try to access admin panel

But in my custom module admin form url doesn't have the word "admin". so only it will redirect to frontend of another store. After that i have changed some modifications on that .htaccess redirection code, Now its working fine!

Thank you to all who review my question!

EDIT : For further details please review this post [Magento redirection with htaccess based on country wise](http://chillydraji.wordpress.com/2014/03/14/magento-redirection-with-htaccess-based-on-country-wise/)