# Magento redirection with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, magento, url-rewriting

I want to redirect example.com to example.au,but at the same time i want to exclude example.com/admin from redirection. Is it possible if yes please provide any rewrite rules.Any help would be appreciated.

Code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$ [NC]
```

#RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ www.example.com.au/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule !^(admin/.*)$ www.example.com.au/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following .htaccess redirection code for access admin

```
GeoIPEnable On 
ReWriteEngine On  
RewriteCond %{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE} IN$   //IN is the country code where you want to redirect
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !admin 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.php [NC]     //admin keywords
RewriteRule ^ http://www.domain.in [R=301,L]  //redirection url
```

In the above example **admin and index.php** are the keywords for accessing admin

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !admin 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.php [NC]
```

It means redirect to specific url in INDIA,only when the current url doesn't have the above keywords(all admin modules only have these keywords).

It would be help you. I'm also using the above same code for my store

All the best

EDIT : You can refer the following threads too for getting some more details

[Some admin modules redirect to frontend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20835530/some-admin-modules-redirect-to-frontend/20943842#20943842)

[Magento redirection with htaccess based on country wise](http://chillydraji.wordpress.com/2014/03/14/magento-redirection-with-htaccess-based-on-country-wise/)

Comment: And more thing dear it shows me that it has both rediect 301 and 302.
I check it with this site redirect-checker.org.

Results:

example.com/
301 Moved Permanently
example.com.au
302 Moved Temporarily
www.example.com.au/
200 OK

Can Please tell where i did mistake?Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi @DRAJI  i had tried your method on htacess file in magento2  IT giving too_many_redirect error. can you please help me to solve this issue?